# Get Direct Reports from Logged in user from Exchange

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

I need to get the direct reports from a logged in user (MVC 4) 
I don't need the names of the direct reports but I do need their email addresses including their proxy addresses. 
So for this reason I need to search through Exchange. I personally have never attempted to search Exchange in the past and everything I find out there tells me how to get from step 8 to the finish line but says nothing about how to go from step 1 to 8.

I can get the current users user name by simply

```
User.Identity.Name.Replace(@"yourdomain\", "")
```

and I have found this example which so far is probably the best example I have found 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184617(v=office.15).aspx

but even with that example the line

```
Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser =
    Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
```

is not actually getting the current user logged into the site.

I really hope someone out there is familiar with this and can get me past this point.

Answer (score 2):

I reworked the sample from the URL as the following LINQPad 4 query. I've found that LINQPad is a great way to experiment because it is very scripty, allowing quick experimentation, and you can easily view data by using the `Dump()` extension method. Purchasing intellisense support is totally worthwhile.

Also, I noticed there is a lot of fine print like:

> The logged-on user must be online for this method to return an AddressEntries collection; otherwise, GetDirectReports returns a null reference. For production code, you must test for the user being offline by using the _NameSpace.ExchangeConnectionMode property, or the _Account.ExchangeConnectionMode property for multiple Exchange scenarios.

and

> If the current user has a manager, GetDirectReports() is called to return an AddressEntries collection that represents the address entries for all the direct reports of user’s manager. If the manager has no direct reports, GetDirectReports returns an AddressEntries collection that has a count of zero.

So there are a lot of assumptions like Exchange is configured properly with Direct Report relationships, and the current user is online...which I believe brings Lync into the equation. Hopefully this LINQPad query will be useful to you. Just copy and paste it into a text editor and name it with the .linq file extension. You'll then be able to open it in LINQPad 4. BTW: You're question caught my attention because there was talk recently at my work of pulling direct reports from Active Directory. I wish I could be more helpful...good luck.

```
<Query Kind="Program">
  <Reference>&lt;ProgramFilesX86&gt;\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll</Reference>
  <Reference>&lt;ProgramFilesX86&gt;\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15\Microsoft.Office.Interop.OutlookViewCtl.dll</Reference>
  <Namespace>Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook</Namespace>
</Query>

void Main()
{
    GetManagerDirectReports();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
private void GetManagerDirectReports()
{
    var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    AddressEntry currentUser = app.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
    if (currentUser.Type == "EX")
    {
        ExchangeUser manager = currentUser.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager();
        manager.Dump();
        if (manager != null)
        {
            AddressEntries addrEntries = manager.GetDirectReports();
            if (addrEntries != null)
            {
                foreach (AddressEntry addrEntry in addrEntries)
                {
                    ExchangeUser exchUser = addrEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.AppendLine("Name: " + exchUser.Name);
                    sb.AppendLine("Title: " + exchUser.JobTitle);
                    sb.AppendLine("Department: " + exchUser.Department);
                    sb.AppendLine("Location: " + exchUser.OfficeLocation);
                    sb.Dump();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using EWS Managed API in conjunction with your code to get the direct reports for a user. As Jeremy mentioned in his response that you need to have your direct report relationships already set up. To help you get started, here some steps to get EWS Managed API up and running:

1. [Download the latest version of EWS Managed API](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42022)
2. [Get started with EWS Managed API client applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn567668%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) to learn about how to reference the assembly, set the service URL, and communicate with EWS.
3. Start working with your code. If you need some functioning code to get you going, check out the [Exchange 2013 101 Code Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-101-Code-3c38582c) that has some authentication code already written and a bunch of examples you can modify to make your own.
4. If you have the email address or user name of the current user you can use the `ResolveName()` method to get to their mailbox to retrieve additional information. Here is an article to help with that method: [How to: Resolve ambiguous names by using EWS in Exchange 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn645423%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Essentially you want to get to the point where you can run a command similar to this:

```
NameResolutionCollection coll = service.ResolveName(NameToResolve, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties));
```

If you give a unique enough value in the **NameToResolve** parameter you should only get back one item in the collection. With that, you can look at the direct reports collection within that one item and see not only the names of their direct reports, but their email addresses as well.

I hope this information helps. If this does resolve your problem, please mark the post as answered.

Thanks,

--- Bob ---